# create animation while user is hovering over canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am trying to add images and animate them when a user is hovering on the canvas, and once they move the mouse off the canvas I want to stop new images appearing.

To achieve this I have tried to set an interval on the new image to trigger every 100ms and then if the user moves the mouse off the canvas this function should stop triggering.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", setInterval(newImage, 100), false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", clearInterval(newImage), false);
```

**JS CODE BELOW**

```js
  //gets canvas element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  function newImage() {

    //random position on the canvas
    var randomPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);

    var images = [
      'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Scratcher.png',
      'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/push_harder_0006.png'
    ];

    var y = window.innerHeight;

    //selects a random image
    var randomImage = parseInt(Math.random() * images.length);

    //IIFE draw
    (function draw() {
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {

        ctx.clearRect(randomPosition - imageObj.width, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);

        y -= 10;

        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, randomPosition - imageObj.width, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);

        if (y > -imageObj.height) {
          requestAnimationFrame(draw)
        }
      };
      imageObj.src = images[randomImage];
    })();
  }

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", setInterval(newImage, 100), false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", clearInterval(newImage), false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is that the interval never clears. You need to assign the interval to a variable and then clear the interval by variable name:

```
var newImageInterval;

canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  newImageInterval = setInterval(newImage, 100);
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  clearInterval(newImageInterval);
}, false);
```

Comment: Looks like clearInterval needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function too.

Comment: Not weird at all. If you don't have the anonymous function you basically call clearInterval in the moment you declare the event listener. You don't give a function to the listener but the return value of setInterval. That's why the anonymous function is needed